# YouTube Android fragment flickering

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

I'm embedding Youtube videos in my Android app using the official SDK. Problem is, the screen gets flickered(black color background for <0.5 seconds) each time a video is initialized.

XML:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/youTube"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cardui"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Watch video"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

             <!-- This is where Youtube fragment will be added -->

          </LinearLayout>
```

Youtube Fragment Code:

```
public static class PlayerYouTubeFrag extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    private String videoId;

    public static PlayerYouTubeFrag newInstance(String videoId) {

        PlayerYouTubeFrag playerYouTubeFrag = new PlayerYouTubeFrag();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("videoId", videoId);
        playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        return playerYouTubeFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        init();

        return super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, bundle);
    }

    private void init() {
        videoId = getArguments().getString("videoId");
        initialize(youtubeKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youtubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
                youtubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                        isFullScreen = b;
                    }
                });

                if (!b) {
                    youtubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
                    youtubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Player initialization failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And finally, adding the Fragment to layout:

```
    mYoutubePlayerFragment = PlayerYouTubeFrag.newInstance(videoId);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).add(R.id.youTube, mYoutubePlayerFragment).commit();
    (findViewById(R.id.youTube)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is because of a weird bug in YouTubeSupportFragment and I'm not the first to notice it. You can get around this, by adding an empty SurfaceView.

Read more here:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4722

Answer (score 2):

The bug is still present, the solution of just adding the `SurfaceView` with `android:width` and `android:height` `0dp` didn't solve my problem. Instead, I had to add the `SurfaceView` in my Layout xml

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

and had to set the visibility of the `SurfaceView` to visible in code while adding the youtube fragment.

```
findViewById(R.id.surface).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(your_holder_id, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

Hope this helps better.